# link_to_unless problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this RoR snippet in a view:

```
<%= link_to_unless(@posts_pages[:previous].nil?, 
  "Previous", 
  blog_with_page_path(:page_num => @posts_pages[:previous])) %>
```

Here blog_with_page is a named route. The snippet works if `@posts_pages[:previous].nil?` is `false` (as expected) and the link is generated correctly. However, when `@posts_pages[:previous].nil?` is `true`, instead of simply getting the `"Previous"` string back, I get an error telling me that the route couldn't be generated using `:page_num=>nil`. Is this the expected behavior? If the condition is met, the route code shouldn't be evaluated, should it?
Here's the complete error:
`blog_with_page_url failed to generate from {:page_num=>nil, :action=>"show", :controller=>"pages"}, expected: {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages"}, diff: {:page_num=>nil}`

I've been looking at the `link_to_unless` code and I don't understand why I get the error since it should be returning simply the name:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb, line 394
  def link_to_unless(condition, name, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
    if condition
      if block_given?
        block.arity <= 1 ? capture(name, &block) : capture(name, options, html_options, &block)
      else
        name
      end
    else
      link_to(name, options, html_options)
    end
  end
```

I'm using Rails 2.3.11 and Ruby 1.8.7

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Ruby is not a lazy language, `blog_with_page_path(:page_num => @posts_pages[:previous])` gets evaluated as soon as you call it, regardless of whether the value ever gets used by `link_to_unless`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the various other answers which explain your problem, why not try this as your solution:

```
link_to( "Previous", blog_with_page_path(:page_num => @posts_pages[:previous]) ) unless @posts_pages[:previous].nil?
```

This will evaluate the "unless" condition first, sparing you the bogus link_to when `@post_pages[:previous]` is nil.

-- EDIT --

As pointed out in the comment, since you need the string back maybe the simplest way is just a ternary:

```
@posts_pages[:previous].nil? ? "Previous" : link_to( "Previous", blog_with_page_path(:page_num => @posts_pages[:previous]) )
```

Comment: but it won't return "Previous" string. So you should use full `if..else` here

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with a ternary. According to @rshallit [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732689/link-to-unless-problem/5732870#5732870) your first solution wouldn't work either.

Comment: Anyway, that would work because "if" and "unless" aren't functions, and the code inside those statements is only evaluated when needed:

Comment: ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > 1/0 unless true
 => nil

Comment: If you think about it, the *point* of an if statement is to only execute some code under a certain condition.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. This code is not "lazy" so it executes all statements. So you can go three ways:

1. Patch it
2. Make simple `if .. else`
3. Hack it:

Like this

```
<%= link_to_unless(@posts_pages[:previous].nil?, 
  "Previous", 
  blog_with_page_path(:page_num => @posts_pages[:previous] || 0)) %>
```

Instead of `0` you can set any number, it will never be setted

Comment: Ehm... It is not a language bug, but in Rails many "lazy" things, so this is a good candidate to be refactored as lazy one.

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments are always evaluated before the function runs, whether or not they are needed:

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :005 > def print_unless(condition, thing_to_print)
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :006?>   puts "I started executing"
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :007?>   puts thing_to_print unless condition
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :008?>   end
 => nil 
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :009 > print_unless(true, 1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
    from (irb):9:in `/'
    from (irb):9
    from :0
```